# What it the best practice to space elements evenly in Ionic?

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I'm trying to space some elements, e.g. ion-cards, evenly within a content area. This is what I get (and what I want), when I'm trying to do it with the Ionic ion-grid, ion-row and ion-col.

[image]

What is the best practise to do so?

Or is this the best way to go?

```
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: flex-start;

  flex-wrap: wrap;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
display: flex;
justify-content: space-evenly;
```

Comment: Thanks Akash for the reply. How would you handle it, if there are 3 elements per row but the last one has only two? Or in general if the number of elements is not a factor of elements per row?

Comment: @JilReg `space-evenly` will basically fill the remaining space equally with the elements present in a particular row. `space-around` is similar, with the exception that it will give more space in between the elements as opposed to the spaces in the beginning and the end. You can try between these two, or if you want to align certain elements differently from the res, you can use the `align-self` property, but there's little you can do.

Comment: However, from what I understand, you want the 2 elements in the last row to follow the same pattern as the above but leave the space in the end blank, you can start by giving a set width to the element according to how many elements you want per row, then the elements that wrap will follow the same pattern as the rest.